# How to get phone name in Android

Tags: android

Is there any way to get phone name in android??. I have tried

```
android.os.Build.DEVICE;
android.os.Build.MODEL;
android.os.Build.PRODUCT;
```

In Samsung Galaxy S. All these are giving GT-19000 as the result,which is the model name. Is there any way I could get Samsung Galaxy S as the result?

Comment: Isn't "Samsung Galaxy S" a marketing name for the product? As such it could be that that name is not referenced anywhere in the software build (so that it could be sold under many different names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your phone settings.Under the About phone section if the phone Model is showing as GT-I900, i think you should be satisfied with that.Like Jean told already Samsung Galaxy S may be juat the marketing name

Comment: yea.it seems like that to me also

Answer (score 2):

GT-19000

well that is the name of the phone...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `android.os.Build.HARDWARE` or `android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER`? What does that give you?

Comment: yea i tried those..android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER and android.os.Build.Brand gives Samsung and android.os.Build.HARDWARE gives smdkc110

Answer (score 1):

Did you try following?

```
android.os.Build.BOARD, 
android.os.Build.BRAND
```

Comment: yea tried those too. BOARD gives GT-I9000 and BRAND gives Samsung

Comment: I too think the name that you expect may be marketing code name and not set to any variables in the firmware.